# Storm Creating Topology

Tags: hadoop, real-time, apache-storm

I am trying to run storm starter example in Linux using Eclipse. I am getting following error and `nexttuple` function is never called.

ERROR:

```
35979 [main] INFO  o.a.s.d.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor cfba8fc6-    81e6-47cb-b8b9-ec7c700f4dfe
35981 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1541437f2a0000a, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
35985 [Thread-10] INFO  o.a.s.event - Event manager interrupted
```

My topology class:

```
package com.storm.MobileCallLogAnalyzer;

import org.apache.storm.tuple.Fields;
import org.apache.storm.tuple.Values;

//import storm configuration packages
import org.apache.storm.Config;
import org.apache.storm.LocalCluster;
import org.apache.storm.StormSubmitter;
import org.apache.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;

//Create main class LogAnalyserStorm submit topology.
public class LogAnalyserStorm {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
      //Create Config instance for cluster configuration
      Config config = new Config();
      config.setDebug(true);

      //Creating Topology
      TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
       builder.setSpout("call-log-reader-spout", new FakeCallLogReaderSpout());

      builder.setBolt("call-log-creator-bolt", new CallLogCreatorBolt())
         .shuffleGrouping("call-log-reader-spout");

      builder.setBolt("call-log-counter-bolt", new CallLogCounterBolt())
         .fieldsGrouping("call-log-creator-bolt", new Fields("call"));

      LocalCluster cluster = new LocalCluster();
      cluster.submitTopology("LogAnalyserStorm", config, builder.createTopology());
      Thread.sleep(10000);

      //Stop the topology
      cluster.shutdown();
   }
 }
```

I'm working on the virtual machine environment `cloudera` ( `cloudera.quickstart` ) so do not know if it is due to the installation of Zookeeper. Any idea?

Comment: Is that all? There's no error in your log, only warn. What happened before "o.a.s.d.supervisor - Shutting down supervisor" ?

Comment: I enclose a link with the output I get: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zbho26gsht57a7h/output.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

```
30736 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] WARN  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - caught end of stream exception
org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x1541468b5e7000d, likely client has closed socket
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.0.jar:1.0.0]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.7.0_67]
30914 [NIOServerCxn.Factory:0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:2000] INFO  o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxn - Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:52175 which had sessionid 0x1541468b5e7000d
```

That seems that the local storm instance is unable to connect to the embedded ZooKeeper instance, whe using local-cluster mode.

See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/storm-user/fLB9KCTeWX0

Maybe, this will help you!

Comment: I have the following configuration for Storm   storm:     `zookeeper.servers:
    - "localhost"

storm.zookeeper.port: 2181

storm.local.dir: /home/cloudera/Downloads/apache-storm-1.0.0/data

nimbus.host: "localhost"

ui.port: 8081

supervisor.slots.ports:
    - 6700
    - 6701
    - 6702
    - 6703`