# Zookeeper, Apache Kafka, Apcahe Storm

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-storm, apache-zookeeper

Below is the details of exception I am getting consistently after two or three days of successfully running. can any one please guide me on this?

```
2016-06-30 21:01:38.184 ERROR 6124 --- [   SyncThread:0] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Unexpected Exception: 

java.nio.channels.CancelledKeyException: null
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.ensureValid(SelectionKeyImpl.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at sun.nio.ch.SelectionKeyImpl.interestOps(SelectionKeyImpl.java:77) ~[na:1.8.0_31]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendBuffer(NIOServerCnxn.java:151) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.sendResponse(NIOServerCnxn.java:1081) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.FinalRequestProcessor.processRequest(FinalRequestProcessor.java:170) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor.flush(SyncRequestProcessor.java:200) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.SyncRequestProcessor.run(SyncRequestProcessor.java:131) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]

2016-06-30 21:01:42.792  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13334ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0008, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:42.792  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0008, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:42.792  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51483 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0008
2016-06-30 21:01:42.892  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:42.892  WARN 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.c.zookeeper-state-factory          : Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
2016-06-30 21:01:43.188  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13334ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0000, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.188  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0000, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.188  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:51487 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0000
2016-06-30 21:01:43.289  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.289  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.storm.zookeeper               : Zookeeper state update: :disconnected:none
2016-06-30 21:01:43.350  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0006, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.350  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0006, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.350  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51488 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0006
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51494
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0000 at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51494
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0000 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51494
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0000, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:43.380  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.381  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] org.apache.storm.zookeeper               : Zookeeper state update: :connected:none
2016-06-30 21:01:43.451  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.451  WARN 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.c.zookeeper-state-factory          : Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
2016-06-30 21:01:43.462  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0017, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.462  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0017, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.462  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51489 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0017
2016-06-30 21:01:43.563  INFO 6124 --- [-14-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.563  WARN 6124 --- [-14-EventThread] o.a.s.c.zookeeper-state-factory          : Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:51495
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0008 at /127.0.0.1:51495
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0008 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /127.0.0.1:51495
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0008, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:43.711  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.727  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0003, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.727  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0003, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.727  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:51490 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0003
2016-06-30 21:01:43.797  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0004, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.797  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0004, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.797  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51491 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0004
2016-06-30 21:01:43.827  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.827  WARN 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.c.zookeeper-state-factory          : Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Writer Zookeeper.
2016-06-30 21:01:43.898  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.898  WARN 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.c.zookeeper-state-factory          : Received event :disconnected::none: with disconnected Reader Zookeeper.
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:51496
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0004 at /127.0.0.1:51496
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0004 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /127.0.0.1:51496
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0004, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:43.902  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:43.960  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13334ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec0001, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:43.960  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec0001, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:43.960  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /127.0.0.1:51492 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec0001
2016-06-30 21:01:44.061  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: SUSPENDED
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /127.0.0.1:51497
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0006 at /127.0.0.1:51497
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0006 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /127.0.0.1:51497
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0006, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:44.103  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:44.161  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] 

[ . . . ]

 o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51499
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0003 at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51499
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0003 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51499
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0003, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:44.222  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:44.916  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Opening socket connection to server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
2016-06-30 21:01:44.916  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Socket connection established to 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, initiating session
2016-06-30 21:01:44.916  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.NIOServerCnxnFactory     : Accepted socket connection from /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51500
2016-06-30 21:01:44.916  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Client attempting to renew session 0x15595e58eec0001 at /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51500
2016-06-30 21:01:44.916  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.ZooKeeperServer     : Established session 0x15595e58eec0001 with negotiated timeout 20000 for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51500
2016-06-30 21:01:44.917  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Session establishment complete on server 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2000, sessionid = 0x15595e58eec0001, negotiated timeout = 20000
2016-06-30 21:01:44.917  INFO 6124 --- [ain-EventThread] o.a.s.s.o.a.c.f.s.ConnectionStateManager : State change: RECONNECTED
2016-06-30 21:01:51.465  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor       : Shutting down and clearing state for id ed72f1e3-177c-43c9-8456-85b2110e5474. Current supervisor time: 1467320495. State: :timed-out, Heartbeat: {:time-secs 1467320448, :storm-id "kafka-1-1467098698", :executors [[8 8] [2 2] [7 7] [3 3] [1 1] [6 6] [9 9] [11 11] [-1 -1] [5 5] [10 10] [4 4]], :port 1027}
2016-06-30 21:01:51.465  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.supervisor       : Shutting down 822c206b-1c84-4c00-bbec-d735a4a1bbae:ed72f1e3-177c-43c9-8456-85b2110e5474
2016-06-30 21:01:51.465  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.config                  : GET worker-user ed72f1e3-177c-43c9-8456-85b2110e5474
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.process-simulator       : Killing process bd3f029a-4da8-4390-9a4f-8b2e25a26b52
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker           : Shutting down worker kafka-1-1467098698 822c206b-1c84-4c00-bbec-d735a4a1bbae 1027
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker           : Terminating messaging context
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.worker           : Shutting down executors
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[8 8]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[8 8]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.467  INFO 6124 --- [8 8]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[8 8]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[2 2]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [2 2]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[2 2]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[2 2]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[7 7]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[7 7]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.468  INFO 6124 --- [7 7]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[7 7]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[3 3]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [3 3]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[3 3]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[3 3]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[1 1]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.469  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[1 1]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [1 1]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[1 1]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[6 6]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[6 6]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [6 6]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[6 6]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor __acker:[9 9]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [r-executor[9 9]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [9 9]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor __acker:[9 9]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.470  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor streamProcessorBolt:[11 11]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [executor[11 11]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [ 11]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor streamProcessorBolt:[11 11]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor __system:[-1 -1]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [ -1]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.471  INFO 6124 --- [executor[-1 -1]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.472  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor __system:[-1 -1]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.472  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[5 5]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.472  INFO 6124 --- [t-executor[5 5]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.472  INFO 6124 --- [5 5]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.473  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shut down executor NotificationProcessorBolt:[5 5]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.473  INFO 6124 --- [      Thread-14] org.apache.storm.daemon.executor         : Shutting down executor spout:[10 10]
2016-06-30 21:01:51.473  INFO 6124 --- [ 10]-send-queue] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.473  INFO 6124 --- [executor[10 10]] org.apache.storm.util                    : Async loop interrupted!
2016-06-30 21:01:51.473  INFO 6124 --- [tor-Framework-0] o.a.c.f.imps.CuratorFrameworkImpl        : backgroundOperationsLoop exiting
2016-06-30 21:01:51.474  INFO 6124 --- [id:0 cport:-1):] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.s.PrepRequestProcessor     : Processed session termination for sessionid: 0x15595e58eec0018
2016-06-30 21:01:51.517  INFO 6124 --- [0:0:0:0:1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec000c, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:51.517  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec000c, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]

2016-06-30 21:01:51.517  INFO 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : Closed socket connection for client /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:51484 which had sessionid 0x15595e58eec000c
2016-06-30 21:01:51.518  INFO 6124 --- [127.0.0.1:2000)] o.a.s.s.org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn  : Client session timed out, have not heard from server in 13333ms for sessionid 0x15595e58eec000a, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
2016-06-30 21:01:51.518  WARN 6124 --- [.0/0.0.0.0:2000] o.a.s.s.o.a.z.server.NIOServerCnxn       : caught end of stream exception

org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.ServerCnxn$EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15595e58eec000a, likely client has closed socket
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:228) ~[storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at org.apache.storm.shade.org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory.run(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:208) [storm-core-1.0.1.jar:1.0.1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_31]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the local storm instance is not able to connect to the embedded Zookeeper instance.

This may help you:

[Error with zookeeper & storm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36737999/error-with-zookeeper-storm)

[Storm Creating Topology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36620196/storm-creating-topology)